KafkaFlow Batch Processing Large Batches Not Working as Expected
I have a .NET app that is using a Batch Consumer with the KafkaFlow library. I am trying to consume large batches of messages (250K) and insert them into a database. I seem to have a configuration issue as I have a couple of problems.

The batch only contains about half the number of messages I expect. I am consistently pulling between 100K and 105K messages even though there is a lag of 2M+ records on the topic. Why is this occurring?
It seems that even with this number of records once the process completes, there is a significant gap (3-5 minutes) from when the process finishes and the next batch is consumed.

Again, I'm almost sure these are configuration issues with how I have the consumer setup. Any input would be appreciated.

assuming you are using BatchConsume config method, what TimeSpan did you pass? Maybe it's hitting the time limit before the batch size limit..
